# Auto open incoming mail from internal email address

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to auto open incoming mails from a specific address.
Found code online which works if I send from Gmail but not from my domain.

```
Public WithEvents objInbox As Outlook.Folder

Public WithEvents objInboxItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set objInbox = Outlook.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set objInboxItems = objInbox.Items
End Sub

'Occurs when incoming emails arrive in Inbox
Private Sub objInboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strSenders As String
    Dim varSenders As Variant
    Dim i As Long
 
    If TypeOf Item Is MailItem Then
       Set objMail = Item
 
       'Change the specific persons
       strSenders = "addr@Mydomain.com;addr@ExDomain.com"
 
       varSenders = Split(strSenders, ";")
 
       'Open the emails from specific persons
       For i = 0 To UBound(varSenders)
           If objMail.SenderEmailAddress = varSenders(i) Then
               objMail.Display
               Exit For
           End If
       Next
    End If
End Sub
```

This question has been asked
[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33336175/vba-script-in-outlook-not-working-for-internal-emails). The solution didn't work.
Could it be premmisions? GPO? Is there an alternative?

Comment: Follow `Set objMail = Item` with `Debug.Print objMail.SenderEmailAddress`. Use that text instead of what you think it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script expects an SMTP address, but internal emails use EX type addresses. You need to use `MailItem.Sender.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress` for the EX type senders.
Modify your script as follows (off the top of my head):

```
Dim senderAddress As String
if objMail.SenderEmailType = "SMTP" Then senderAddress  = objMail.SenderEmailAddress
ElseIf objMail.SenderEmailType = "EX" Then senderAddress = objMail.Sender.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress 
Else senderAddress = ""

For i = 0 To UBound(varSenders)
      If senderAddress = varSenders(i) Then
         objMail.Display
         Exit For
      End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you!!! works like a magic! 
i init senderAddress = objMail.Sender.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
inside the for loop since all the emails are internal

appreciate it!